# Error at runtime while deleting a string from a pointer to pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays

I was trying to add a string to end of a pointer to pointer array, or insert a string in a selected position, then delete a selected element, using 3 function.

The first function I used to add a string to the end of a pointer to pointer:

```
char **add(char **pp, int size, char *str)
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        pp = new char *[size+1];
    }
    else
    {
        char **temp = new char *[size+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = pp[i];
        }
        delete[]pp;
        pp = temp; 
    }
    pp[size] = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    strcpy(pp[size], str);
    return pp;
}
```

The second function I used to insert a string in a selected position:

```
char **InsPtr(char **pp, int size, int ncell, char *str)
{
    char**temp = new char *[size+1];  //добавить новый элемент [size+1]
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < size + 1; j++)
    {
        if (j != ncell)
        {
            temp[j] = pp[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[j]=new char[ strlen(str)+1];
            strcpy(temp[j], str);
        }
    }
    delete[] pp;
    pp = temp;
    return pp;
}
```

And here is the function I used to delete any string I choose:

```
char **DelPtr(char **pp, int size, int ncell)
{
    char**temp = new char*[size-1];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (i != ncell)
        {
            temp[j] = pp[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    delete[]pp[ncell];
    pp[ncell] = 0;
    delete[] pp;
    pp = temp;
    return pp;
}
```

I used `**add(char **pp, int size, char *str)` to add 4 strings to the array, then insert a string in a selected position by `**InsPtr(char **pp, int size, int ncell, char *str)`, or delete a string by `**DelPtr(char **pp, int size, int ncell)`, and it works correctly without any error.

But when I use `**InsPtr(char **pp, int size, int ncell, char *str)`, then after this function I use `**DelPtr(char **pp, int size, int ncell)`
I got an error at runtime.

Here is main function:

```
void main()
{   
    int size = 0; 
    char **pp = 0;
    pp = add(pp, size, "1111");
    size++;
    pp = add(pp, size, "2222");
    size++;
    pp = add(pp, size, "3333");
    size++;
    pp = add(pp, size, "4444");
    size++;
    int insert=2,DelS= 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(pp + i) << endl;
    }
    pp = InsPtr(pp, size, insert, "natasha");
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << *(pp + i) << endl;
    }
    pp = DelPtr(pp, size, DelS);
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    {
        cout << *(pp + i) << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Here is the result i got before the error at runtime:

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

Insert in the second index "natasha":

```
1111
2222
natasha
3333
4444
```

Delete the second index "natasha":

```
1111
2222
3333
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `std::string`?

Comment: i don't want to use a ready class, just trying to use c.

Comment: After **insert("Natasha"…** there is no **size++**. **size** should be incremented by **insert()** then this problem can't arise.

Comment: I assume you mean "C++".  `std::string` **is** idiomatic C++, whereas pointers-to-pointers is definitely not.

Comment: Is your main concert the loss of "4444" after **delete("Natasha"…** ?

Comment: i loss it, and got an error at runtime @ArifBurhan

Comment: I tried what you said and got "4444", but also got an error at runtime @ArifBurhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `size++;` after `pp = InsPtr(pp, size, insert, "natasha");`
and `size--;` after  `pp = DelPtr(pp, size, DelS);` :)

like this:

```
void main()
{   
    int size = 0; 
    char **pp = 0;
    pp = add(pp, size, "1111");
    size++;
    pp = add(pp, size, "2222");
    size++;
    pp = add(pp, size, "3333");
    size++;
    pp = add(pp, size, "4444");
    size++;
    int insert=2,DelS= 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    cout << *(pp + i) << endl;
    }
     pp = InsPtr(pp, size, insert, "natasha");
     cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
    cout << *(pp + i) << endl;
    }
    size++;
    pp = DelPtr(pp, size, DelS);
    cout << endl;
    size--;
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    {
        cout << *(pp + i) << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```